# NHibernate - can't compile mapping file

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

This is my domain class:

```
public class User
{
    public Guid id { get; set; }

    public string firstName { get; set; }

    public string lastName { get; set; }

    public string mailAddress { get; set; }
}
```

This is my mapping file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="Test" namespace="Test.model">

  <class name="User" >
    <id name="id">
      <generator class="guid"/>
    </id>
    <property name="firstName"  />
    <property name="lastName" />
    <property name="mailAddress" />
  </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

This is My hibernate-cfg file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

```
<property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
<property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
<property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.MySqlDataDriver</property>
<property name="connection.connection_string">Server=localhost;Database=vbook;User ID=root;Password=ziben</property>
<!--<property name="proxyfactory.factory_class">NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle</property>-->

<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
<property name="generate_statistics">true</property>
<property name="show_sql">true</property>


<mapping file="data/mapping/User.hbm.xml" />
```

This is how I create session factory:

```
 var configuration = new Configuration();
 configuration.Configure();

 _sessionFactory = configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
```

I get the following exception: 
Could not compile the mapping document: data/mapping/User.hbm.xml

I can't understand why.

Help please.

Comment: Give stack trace so that looking into nested exception, it will be easy to detect exact reason.

Answer (score 1):

Any C# property of your entiy must be declared as **virtual**. Change your class this way:

```
public class User
{
    public virtual Guid id { get; set; }
    public virtual string firstName { get; set; }
    public virtual string lastName { get; set; }
    public virtual string mailAddress { get; set; }
}
```